# Rendering of html and css on safari with ios 13 ipad is wrong, while it renders correctly on ios 12 same ipad

Tags: css, ipad, ios13

I use html and css to render a page which has been in place and working for all ios devices and ios software versions. But recently with ios 13, the rendering of the page got all messed up on safari. I tried the same html/css on the same ipad with ios 12.x and 13.x on safari. It works on ios12.x but not on ios 13.x. Any ideas or known issues?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question respectively, e.g. by providing the code you've tried so far.